# How to learn something about the pool when using a mixed model

Tags: regression, mixed-model, modeling

I'm familar with (linear) mixed models in general but I never really got the understanding for it. When reading about them I get the single ideas and concepts and it always seems quite reasonable and even kind of obvious.
But I never learnt to adapt them to my problems or to understand when and why I should use them.

At the moment, this is such a situation: I'm studying about a dozen of sensors, each dozen from another manufacturer and I wonder (again): Would it make sense to use a mixed model here?

**What would I gain? What could I gain?**

Some background information: The sensors are gas sensors, means, when gas is injected their resistance will drop according to the amount of the present gas concentration. They are also subject to almost each external influences like temperature, humidity and other gases.
My task is quite simple: To figure out which sensor is better. I performed already some crucial investigations and so on but I have some ressources left to dive a bit deeper into this chapter. Either I close it or I try to extend my knowledge.
I rather would like to do the latter. What would a mixed model reveal that a *simple* model wouldn't?

**edit:**
The sensors are investigated through several experiment designs, it is mostly something like:

```
    Temperature Humidity H2 CO C2H2
1   50  30  250 250 50
2   18  11  100 100 100
3   18  11  500 500 100
4   18  11  100 500 25
...
```

The sensors itself are measured each second and a datapoint is generated by using the mean of a minute. So, for different aspects I'm also looking at their time signals and how they are behaving in terms of equilibrium and so on.
The single data of sensor is just only **time** versus **resistance**. So, there is a datalogger which records all the resistance values continously. Other parameters like temperature, CO and so on are measured by other devices.

To figure out what better means, is also kind of a question. It depends.  But there are some crucical requirements:

- the more gas present, the stronger the signal should be
- a linear relationship is "better" because it is easier to handle
- the sensors must now show influences to other gases or at least they shouldn't cause stronger signals
- sensors / sensor signals should be reproducible (means, 100 ppm CO will always cause the same outcome)
- sensors of the same manufacturer should behave as identical as possible
- gas influence should prevail other influences like temperature
- the lower the detection limit, the better (means, when a sensor is able to detect already 30 ppm CO it is better than reacting not before 100 ppm CO)
- the same goes to the upper limit

I think these are the most important aspects I have in mind right now. There are probably some others, especially more technical issues but they come second.

Comment: Could you describe the investigations you already performed? It would be quite helpful for us to provide a good answer. For each sensor, what data do you have? Thanks!

Comment: If you have repeated measures, or otherwise clustered data, this is a primary reason to consider a mixed effects model. However you need to provide more information - for one thing, what do you mean by "better" here: *To figure out which sensor is better.*, and in general please just give us more info.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I added some information, hope that helps in return? What exactly are repeated measures? That units are measured over and over again or that e.g. a single operating point is measured again and again? I guess the sensors are kind of clustered as I compare 2-3 manufacturers against each other?